# What is the special macro of buffer size in standard C library?

Tags: c

I saw this special macro when I read a source code. If I remember correctly, it is defined in the standard library.

The name of this macro is related to the buffer size, and in my machine its implementation is 1024.

Now I want to use it to initialize the buffer but I forgot what it is called.

So is there any one who can help me make my code look more professional?

*If I don't know what I am looking for specifically, how can I clearly say what I need?*

Comment: Which buffer? What kind of buffer? Something like `PATH_MAX` (which is part of POSIX, not C).

Comment: not a clue, sorry...

Comment: Please make your question first to look more professional. Currently it is "I saw  something somewhere doing something, what can I do with that?".

Comment: @EugeneSh. In fact, I feel that I am quite clear, and I also got the answer I want, thanks.

Comment: Well, you've got lucky. Note that your question is on hold as unclear, and I am not on the voters list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about `BUFSIZ`? It's a macro provided by `<stdio.h>` and it expands to the size of the buffer used by `setbuf()`.

I'm not sure what use it has in your own code.

Comment: It's GNU C specific if I am not mistaken..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Dude, I got my information straight from C99.pdf (7.19.1).

Comment: Then I am mistaken :)

Comment: This is exactly what I want!